# How can I remove this folder?

Tags: linux-mint, rmdir

I have a folder that appeared suddenly and I want to get rid of it.

I'm using Linux Mint btw.

The location is ~/.local/share/Trash/files/**AhCBFJnAYJ**

It is about 1GB in size and I have no memory of creating it. I can't list the folder's contents either. I've tried emptying the trash bin and using bleachbit, but nothing seems to help.

I would greatly appreciate any advice. Thanks for reading!

Comment: you maybe try `sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/files/AhCBFJnAYJ`

Comment: This won't execute. It's trying to process the command, but it never finishes. I've tried so many variants of this.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a folder with its contents just type

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/files/AhCBFJnAYJ
```

This should be able to be removed by giving root permission.

As this didnt work then it requires you to take ownership again:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.local/share/Trash/files/AhCBFJnAYJ
```

where $USER stands for your user name in the path name.

Comment: I have tried using the same command before (even using sudo!). Whenever I try to interact with it the command never executes. It will say its running the job, but it never finishes.

Comment: @Diogenes I have updated the comment. It requires you take ownership again.